gglikert plot in R with perecentages
i have a data frame in R called df :
df
     Item Strongly Disagree Disagree    So So    Agree Strongly Agree
1  BRAZIL          13.33333 25.83333 15.83333 15.83333       29.16667
2 GERMANY          20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 10.00000       30.00000
3   ITALY          40.00000  0.00000 60.00000  0.00000        0.00000
4     USA           0.00000 16.25000 22.50000 28.75000       32.50000

i want to create a likert scale plot using ggplot2 or gglikert from ggstats. Specifically i want in the y axis to have the countries and in x axis the Likert levels.But i want to be sorted   in an descending order according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two higher categories will be in an ascending order).
How can i do this in R using gglikert?
data :
dput(df)
structure(list(Item = c("BRAZIL", "GERMANY", "ITALY", "USA"), 
    `Strongly Disagree` = c(15, 20, 40, 13.3333333333333), Disagree = c(15, 
    40, 40, 20), `So So` = c(20, 10, 20, 13.3333333333333), Agree = c(15, 
    20, 0, 40), `Strongly Agree` = c(35, 10, 0, 13.3333333333333
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")


Which data frame do you want to use (DF or df)?

@Edward sorry is the same.I edited.

@Roman i am sorry the data  dput(df) were wrong.I edited.

from that point: df %>%   pivot_longer(-c(Item)) %>%    ggplot(aes(value, Item, fill = name)) +     geom_col() what do you want?

@Roman To be sorted as i explained in the OP. btw i don't want stacked bar plot

You can try
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstat)
likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly Disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "So So",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly Agree"
)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Item)) %>% 
  mutate(value  = ifelse(Item == "USA" & name == "Strongly Agree", 14, value)) %>% 
  split(.$Item) %>% 
  map2_dfc(., names(.), ~tibble(rep(.x$name,times = round(.x$value))) %>% set_names(.y))  %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels))) %>% 
  gglikert(sort = "descending")


To sort by the lower bounds, you can use this answer:
sort the gglikert chart based on the combination percentages in R
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Item)) %>% 
  mutate(value  = ifelse(Item == "USA" & name == "Strongly Agree", 14, value)) %>% 
  split(.$Item) %>% 
  map2_dfc(., names(.), ~tibble(rep(.x$name,times = round(.x$value))) %>% set_names(.y))  %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels))) %>% 
  gglikert(sort = "ascending") +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),1, 0),
                  FUN = sum))


Why you set ifelse(Item == "USA" & name == "Strongly Agree", 14, value).Is there any more automatic way to do it ?.Also 33% must be below 30%. But more important i receive no plot.Just an empty panel with the countries in the y axis . Warning messages: 1: Computation failed in stat_prop(). Caused by error in aggregate.data.frame(): ! no rows to aggregate  2: Computation failed in stat_prop(). Caused by error in aggregate.data.frame(): ! no rows to aggregate  3: Removed 8 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (geom_text()).


the percantages need to sum up to 100%. 2. try ascending order then 3. have you installed >R version 4.3.0?


i have 4.3.3 installed.The problem insists

ahh. Sorry you have to specify the levels. Updated the answer.

ok but still the 33% appears above 30%.Ascending order  does not help
